# Is there anyway to refresh all cell with formula with openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, vba, openpyxl

I have a problem that openpyxl didn't calculate the formula cell except I pick it up with 'F2' and then enter.
for example,
I have this code

```
ws.cell(row=1,column=1,value="=VLOOKUP(CF{0},VlookupSheet!$A:$H,8,FALSE)".format(2))
```

I expect to see a value from the Vlookupsheet by the vlookup formula.
However,  Its  show as an empty cell except I refresh it manually.

Furthermore.  I have a dictionary that read this cell as a key to write value to cell. Since this vlookup failed to create one my dictionary just didn't work.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: openpyxl never evaluates formulae. The documentation makes this very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `Application.CalculateFull`. It will refresh all cells.

[Application.CalculateFull method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.calculatefull)